# Can you perform a Kernel Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a Kernel Logistic Regression in R. Is there a package that does this?

Comment: `RSiteSearch("Kernel")` should help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stats::ksmooth` gives you the Nadaraya–Watson kernel regression:

```
with(cars, {
    plot(speed, dist>40)
    lines(ksmooth(speed, dist>40, "normal", bandwidth = 2), col = 2)
    lines(ksmooth(speed, dist>40, "normal", bandwidth = 6), col = 3)
})
```

[image]